# VBA - Sheets.count - subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

Below is a macro which I wrote about three years ago, when I was a much less proficient VBA coder than I am today.  There are a number of obvious things which I would simplify/do differently today.  However, it is still in use and generally works.  The manager of the relevant admin process copies and pastes this code into different workbooks every time we set up a new customer, and changes around a few of the variables.  This has worked fine until today, when it has suddenly started generating a "subscript out of range" error when used in a new worksheet.

The error generates on the line `workdaybook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy salesBook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)`.  I have checked and "salesBook" has been defined.  However, hovering the cursor over "salesBook.worksheets(Sheets.Count) brings up a "subscript out of range" message.

I know that overall, this code isn't the best-written in the world, but I am puzzled by it suddenly failing on this line, having worked previously for about three years when pasted into multiple different workbooks.

```
Option Explicit

Sub salescalc()

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'On Error GoTo Errorcatch

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim salesBook As Workbook
    Dim CurrentWeekSheet As Worksheet

    Set salesBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set CurrentWeekSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim workday As Date
    Dim nextworkday As Date
    Dim workdaybook As Workbook

    workday = InputBox("Insert date in format dd/mm/yy", "userdate")
    nextworkday = workday + 1

    'find bottom row of "table"

    Dim bottomrow As Range

    For x = 1 To 6500
        If CurrentWeekSheet.Cells(x, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 19 Then
            coloured_row = Range("A" & x).Row
        End If
    Next x

    Set bottomrow = Range("A" & coloured_row)


    'finds beginning and end of day's range

    Dim workdayrange As Range
    Dim nRow As Long
    Dim workday_date As Variant
    Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long


    ' Work out where the range should start - works
    For nRow = 1 To 65536 'change this to xldown
        If CurrentWeekSheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value = workday Then
            'nStart = nRow + 3
            nStart = nRow + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow

    ' Work out where the range should end - works
    For nRow = nStart To 65536
        If CurrentWeekSheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value = nextworkday Or Range("A" & nRow).Row = bottomrow.Row Then
            nEnd = nRow
            Exit For
        End If
    Next nRow

    'distinction between bottom row and next date - offset less for bottomrow

    If nEnd = bottomrow.Row Then
        nEnd = nEnd
    Else
        If nEnd <> bottomrow.Row Then
            nEnd = nEnd - 2
        End If
    End If

    Set workdayrange = CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd)

    workday_date = Format(workday, "dd-mm-yy")

    'identify which month is referred to based on date input by user (workday_date)- this will need to be updated in 2016
    If Year(workday_date) <> 2017 Then
        MsgBox "Date must be in 2017.  If you require info for another year, please contact xxxxx."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Workbooks.Open ("U:\\(Folder)\\(subfolder)\\(Subfolder)\\2017\\" & workday_date & ".xlsx")
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If

    Set workdaybook = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim workdaysheet As Worksheet
    Set workdaysheet = ActiveSheet

    workdaybook.Activate
    workdaybook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy salesBook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "salesdata"
    Dim sheetforcopy As Worksheet
    Set sheetforcopy = Sheets.Add
    sheetforcopy.Name = "Sheetforcopy"

    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd).EntireRow.Copy
    sheetforcopy.Range("A185").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sheetforcopy.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd).Formula = "=if(D185<>0,SUMIFS(salesdata!E:E,salesdata!B:B,""*""&D185&""*"",salesdata!B:B,""*Total*""),"""")"

    sheetforcopy.Range("L" & nStart & ":L" & nEnd).Formula = "=IF(IF(ISNUMBER(B185)=TRUE,COUNTIF(salesdata!B:B,""*""&B185&""*"")-1,"""")=-1,0,IF(ISNUMBER(B185)=TRUE,COUNTIF(salesdata!B:B,""*""&B185&""*"")-1,""""))"

    sheetforcopy.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd).Copy
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd).Copy
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    sheetforcopy.Range("L" & nStart & ":L" & nEnd).Copy
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("L" & nStart & ":L" & nEnd).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("L" & nStart & ":L" & nEnd).Copy
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("L" & nStart & ":L" & nEnd).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("salesdata").Delete
    Worksheets("sheetforcopy").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    workdaybook.Close
    CurrentWeekSheet.Activate
    CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart).Select

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Exit Sub
    'Errorcatch: MsgBox "Error - (confidential message deleted)."

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do not specify a workbook the `Sheets.Count` operates on the active workbook. Try `salesBook.Sheets(salesBook.Sheets.Count)` instead.

Comment: Since you are activating workdaybook.Activate
            workdaybook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy salesBook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)   Sheets.count is most likely counting workdaybook and not salesBook.

Comment: The error you're describing arises when `sheets.count` is a number greater than there are sheets.  The above comments are spot on.

Comment: The amount of replication of `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` and `Select` is really scaring me here... I'd suggest fixing up a lot of this

Comment: I was re-writing this code, to tidy it up. I noticed that thet first 50% of the code helps define this range `Set workdayrange = CurrentWeekSheet.Range("F" & nStart & ":F" & nEnd)` by working out what `nStart` and `nEnd` are. However, the variable `workdayrange` isnt used anywhere?